# ASP.Net/C# How can method string return be stored for later use in another method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, methods

Can someone please advise on how to store the output of this method return in a usable string or char format that could be used as a variable in a different method? I've tried passing by value, by reference, in array format, char format implementations, string format implementations, `Char.ToString()`, `String.ToCharArray()`, etc.

I defined a timer to have accessTokenRequest() execute at set intervals:

```c#
protected void accessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = randomCharGen();
    //accessLiteral.Text = randomCharGen(); //this generates automated new values upon each refresh interval as what is stored in the variable
    accessLiteral.Text = test;
}
```

```asp
<asp:Timer ID="accessTimer" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="accessTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="accessUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="accessLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="accessTimer" EventName="tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This response is what I am trying to store for later use in the `Web.UI.Timer` function:

```c#
private static string accessTokenRequest()
{          
    var client = new RestClient("'api'");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    request.AddParameter("refresh_token", "'token'");
    request.AddParameter("client_id", "'id'");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
   
    dynamic access = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);      
    string[] accessTokenArray = new string[1];
    accessTokenArray[0] = access.access_token.ToString();
    return accessTokenArray[0];    

}
```

I can parse the JSON response to obtain the desired field, however, I have not been able to find a way to or create the result where I can just store the target value in a variable for later use without the method being called again.  Short of implementing a database to store the responses and then consume from there (undesired), I'm not too sure what other options I might have.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `MemoryCache` is where I would suggest starting. Or a `static` field.

Comment: This is an XY question. Please phrase the question as to the problem you have rather than the problem with the solution you have. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: A cookie. This is the HTTP standard for short lived variables you need to store for different methods/pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought about using

window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date

window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

*https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Also maybe consider using Session variables